# How to trigger an action if there's only one key being pressed?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, script, autohotkey, key-binding

Here's my current script:

```
Shift::Send ^{Space}
```

It doesn't only trigger <kbd>^{Space}</kbd> on pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> alone, it also triggers on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (*just these two keys*) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (*just these two keys*) **if <kbd>Shift</kbd> is the last released**, is there a way to trigger <kbd>^{Space}</kbd> if <kbd>Shift</kbd> is the **only** key being pressed?

AutoHotkey Version: 1.1.33.09.

Comment: Works fine for me as written when only pressing Shift alone... adding other keys to the combo also does not result in the hotkey getting triggered, as expected. Tested with AutoHotkey v 1.1.33.0.9

Comment: @JJohnston2 "it also triggers on Alt+Shift (**just these two keys**), and Ctrl+Shift (**just these two keys**)", have you tested only pressing Alt+Shift or Ctrl+Shift? My AHK version is the same as yours.

Comment: @JJohnston2 As long as the Shift key is the **last released**, the action _will_ be triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clarifications added to the original post were helpful.

Shift is not like a normal hotkey, so the order you press the keys in matters. For example, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> does not necessarily trigger the same hotkey as pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Also just for info, hotkey definitions fire on the key-up event, unless you have a separate "key up" hotkey definition (for example if `Shift Up::` is added to the script, then the original `Shift::` code now fires on `Shift Down`, where-as previously it would fire on `Shift Up`)

At any rate, if you put a tilde (`~`) in front of a hotkey definition it will execute your code but doesn't block the key press at all from going through, so for any number of special `Shift` combinations that you don't want to trigger, you can try turning the hotkey off and then back on.  When multiple hotkey definitions are stacked it executes the same code at the bottom for any of them, until the Return statement...

```
~+LControl::
~+RControl::
~+LAlt::
~+RAlt::
~Shift & Alt::
~Shift & Control::
~^Shift::
~!Shift::
    Tooltip % "A_ThisHotkey=" A_ThisHotkey
    Hotkey, Shift, Off
    KeyWait, Shift
    Hotkey, Shift, On
    
    Sleep 100   ; comment this out if not debugging
    ToolTip
Return

Shift::MsgBox
```

I started out with the debug code above, but I don't think it even needs anything to execute as long as there are hotkeys defined for the use cases you don't want to trigger... i.e., this appears to work just as well...

```
~+LControl::
~+RControl::
~+LAlt::
~+RAlt::
~Shift & Alt::
~Shift & Control::
~^Shift::
~!Shift::
Return

Shift::MsgBox
```

If you want to see the difference in behavior between different orders of keystrokes though, leave off of the first few hotkey definitions and run this code below, which will show you the difference it makes in pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, vs. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Without the other hotkey definitions, this shows that it allows you to distinguish the key order, which allows you to actually have a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> hotkey that does not fire on <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (i.e., it's a 'feature', not a bug)

```
~^Shift::
~!Shift::
    Tooltip % "A_ThisHotkey=" A_ThisHotkey
    Hotkey, Shift, Off
    KeyWait, Shift
    Hotkey, Shift, On
    
    Sleep 100   ; comment this out if not debugging
    ToolTip
Return

Shift::MsgBox
```

Comment: That was incredibly helpful, thanks! I've seen all the hotkeys shown in the tooltips except `Shift & Alt` and `Shift & Control`, I'm wondering how to trigger them?

Comment: And why `~+Alt` _can't_ replace `~+LAlt` and `~+RAlt`?

Comment: And if I want to trigger Ctrl+Space using Shift, what would be the best code?

Comment: You can probably replace some of the left/right keys with generics, I was just writing them all out for testing purposes... can just experiment. For the last comment I believe you can do Shift::Send, ^{Space}

Comment: Per my tests, given the presence of the preceding hotkeys, `Shift & Alt` and `Shift & Control` are safe to remove; and `~+Alt` indeed cannot replace `~+LAlt` and `~+RAlt`.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to upvote [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410915/7881859) for bringing syntax highlighting for AHK scripts.

Comment: You may need to have the separate `LAlt` and `RAlt` which designate physical keys vs. just `Alt` which makes sense a modifier but not as a particular key (where Alt := LAlt || RAlt).  Or maybe that doesn't make sense. Just a thought